# Can we create queue data consumers?

Tags: karate

Consider I have rabbitmq or Amazon SQS from which I have to consume the data and validate the same with data in DB.

Is it possible to write consumer using karate which simply consumes data from a queue and stores it and validate against the data in DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using Java interop you can do anything. Refer this example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#consumer-provider-example