# Karate API Testing - How do i read the response and validate from another service consuming the messages from the queue - see diagram below

Tags: message-queue, karate

We have multiple services posting and consuming from multiple Rabbit queues. I want to post my request from the first service and read the response generated by the last service and validate that in Karate API test framework.

Here is the flow of the application -

my feature post to rest service -> message queue1 -> consumed by service 2 -> message queue -> consumed by service 3 and a response is generated (I want to read and assert this response in my feature)

[here is the image with the flow of services and message queues in between](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IC4CY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use Java interop and write some custom code (one time). Here's an example that should answer all your questions, including how to handle async events: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69406420/143475

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55235584/143475